# SQL Server 2008 Express, just create a few tables and run queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express, as I just want to create a few tables and run queries against them. After installing I am a little unstuck. I have an "instance" running, but I am not sure how to proceed and see the GUI where I can create tables/run queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the local database.  Then you can create a database and it's tables via the menus or via SQL commands.